# Call Function from Dynamic Library

Tags: c++, windows, function, dll, dynamic

What would be the best way to, if possible, load a dynamic library and call one of it's functions, when we don't know the name of the function during compile-time?

For example, is there a way to make a program that reads a string from a file and then loads a DLL and searches for and calls a function with its name being the string read from the file?

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I was aiming this to be more of a general question; I am on Linux right now, so I would prefer Linux, but a Windows example would work too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Using_explicit_run-time_linking) on Wikipedia of all places showing how to use the [LoadLibrary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function at runtime. You will see that the function name is specified as a string. You would need to write the code to search for the function name and pass it to similar code.

On Linux you can do this with [dlopen() and dlsym()](http://reemus.blogspot.com/2009/02/dynamic-load-library-linux.html) functions.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know of a Linux example?

Comment: LoadLibrary() is a Windows function, I thought you had a DLL which normally means Windows. I just added a link to a linux example.

Comment: Thanks for the Linux example.

Comment: btw using `dlsym` for functions yields undefined behaviour, according to the C and C++ standards. Practically however its fine to do so.