# link dll functions at runtime

Tags: dll

My program requires some function in a dll at runtime. How do I tell where the dll is? I can copy the dll into the program directory or system 32. Is there other neat way of doing this? Thank you. Also I am working in C++.

Comment: There's not enough informaiton here to answer the question.  What's your coding environment?  (.NET, PHP, Java, VBScrip files, classic ASP, C++, etc).  Can you be more specific and more descriptive?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using native code (C/C++/Delphi) or .NET? You should see my answer to [Call Function from Dynamic Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520584/call-function-from-dynamic-library) for an example of how to do this with a native (not .NET) DLL.