# Trying to register a dll but getting error DllRegisterServer entry point was not found

Tags: dll, regsvr32, dllregistration

I have a .net assembly dll which i am trying to register using regsvr32, but get the following error:

"dll loaded but DllRegisterServer entry point was not found "

getting this error while registering the other dlls also.

Answer (score 6):

There is a Microsoft KB [article on regsvr32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873) that you should read. A DLL must be a COM library for it to be registered. This exposes the entry function ([DllRegisterServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) noted in the error message. This might not be there is the DLL is not designed to be registered, or is "corrupt" in some way. You can find out if a function is exported using [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html).

It would be great if you could provide information on whether you have the source code for the DLLs and why you need to register them. If you have a plain Win32 DLL you can access functions by loading it with [LoadLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520584/call-function-from-dynamic-library/5520610#5520610) from native code. You need to use P/Invoke from .NET code.

Comment: I have this problem on a .dll that is registered and works fine when the project is set for x86 CPU but gives an error(not registered) for x86. When trying to register it, regsvr32 gives me this error. Any ideas on that?